# Videocard makes strange noise

Tags: noise

Few days ago I bought Gigabyte's Nvidia 770GTX videocard. I noticed that it makes some cracky noise. It's not actually loud but I could hear it sitting at least from 40cm from my PC.

I made stress test for it I used Furmark, also I played Crysis and Battlefield 3 maxed out. So I realized that noise is NOT getting louder.

I think it's not fans.

Is it okay? What could it be and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably it is an electrical problem...

But first things first...

1) Verify cables and connector, unplug end plug again pressing a little more
2) Remove the card from the socket, verify all connections are clean and insert it again

If the card make the same noises before the OS loads (load the drivers for the card) then for sure it is a card problem... change it!

Comment: well, after unplug-and-plug actions it begin to sound more quiet.
And before the OS is load there are no such noises.

Comment: looks like a driver problem...
go to the vendor site and download a newer driver and test...
if problem persists also download a driver (if available) oder then the one you have...
if the problem remains... then for sure it is an hardare problem...
try to get a replacement from the shop where you bought it.

Comment: Well, thats kinda strenght. Never tought that GPU software problem cause hardware problem

Comment: You would be suprised... 
I work with PC hardware since the original PC's... with the ISA sockets... then VESA... then PCI (a welcome update)... then PCI-X... then Cross-Bridge PCI-X... 
I'm curious what's next!!!

Comment: didn't you forget AGP? :)

Comment: but is this problem is such fatal?

Comment: hah in the shop they was like, ah, that problem again! I change it on MSI 770Gtx, and this thing is quiet as cat :3

Comment: Ya... AGP too... I was only mentioning generic bus tech... AGP was a graphic only pseu solution for graphic performance...

Comment: Yep... and AGP...

Comment: Haha, where have you been whole year?

Comment: Having a life!!! ;-) ...